# Set of rules with `rpart.rules`

Tags: r, caret, rpart

This code

```
data(ptitanic)
model <- rpart(survived ~ ., data = ptitanic, cp = .02)
rules <- rpart.rules(model)
```

prints the leaves of the tree as follows

```
survived                                             
     0.05 when sex is   male & age <  9.5 & sibsp >= 3
     0.17 when sex is   male & age >= 9.5             
     0.73 when sex is female                          
     0.89 when sex is   male & age <  9.5 & sibsp <  3
```

The tree is the following:

[image]

The first column, `survived`, contains the percentage that we see shown in the center of each leaf. Instead, I would like to have the another column with the remaining percentage, i.e. the one that appears in the lower part of each leaf. Meaning what:

```
   0.02  0.05 when sex is   male & age <  9.5 & sibsp >= 3
   0.61  0.17 when sex is   male & age >= 9.5             
   0.36  0.73 when sex is female                          
   0.02  0.89 when sex is   male & age <  9.5 & sibsp <  3
```